# How to get data from additional tables using EF/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have following three tables

```
Employee(empid, name)
Role(roleid, name)
EmpRoleMap(mapid, empid,roleid)
```

In the index view I show the link of employees with edit link with each employee. When user clicks on edit it opens the edit screeen for the selected employee.

For this page to render I am making two calls to database. First is to get the details about selected employee. Seconds is to query the EmpRoleMap table to find out what all roles that employee belongs to.

I want to do the same stuff in single database call, i.e single call would give me the details about the employee and the roleID from EmpRoleMap & RoleName list for the given Employee.

I am using Code First approach with Scaffolding.

How can I do this using EntityFramework? Can we use "Include" clause with LINQ to get the additional data from other tables (here EmpRoleMap,Role).

Comment: What stops you from adding all the 3 tables in a single EDM? Check this link here. It might help you. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=600

Comment: You can use `Include` if your model has the appropriate `Navigation properties` (something like a `public virtual IList<Role> Roles {get;set;}` in the `Employee` class, for example). If it hasn't, you'll have to query with joins. By the way, with code first, you should not have an `EmpRoleMap` entity, as it's just a relationaship table (with no further info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a good Entity Model design. I'm going to try to show you an example of what I'm saying, but remember that at this moment I cannot check the code.

```
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeRoles")]

        public decimal empid { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<EmpRoleModel> EmployeeRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleModel
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal roleid { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmpRoleModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Employee")]

        public decimal empid { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Role")]

        public decimal roleid { get; set; }

        public virtual EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual RoleModel     Role     { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you can navigate to employee roles by the EmployeeRoles property.

Please try this code and give me feedback.